# Retrieve data from wordpress db via input and put those result in dropdown

Tags: wp-query, database, ajax

I am very new in wordpress development and I have a table that has zipcode values and school names( i have probably thousands of results in the table). What i want to do is retrieving zipcode from the user and according to zipcode value, search it in the table and with the results of it, display those school names related to that zipcode user enter. So far I am able to get the zipcode and search it via:(This is edited part and most updated code i have right now)

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="zipcode">Zip Codes
      <input type="text" class="form-control postcode" name="postalCode" />
      <input type="button" id="findschoolname">
    </div>
    <div id="replacedropwdown">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Institutions
       <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#"</a></li>
           </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#findschoolname").click(function(){
 var postcode = jQuery('.postcode').val();
     var postData = {
         action: 'finescroolname',
         postcode: postcode,
     }
     var adminurl = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
 jQuery.post(ajaxurl, postData, function(response) {
 jQuery('#replacedropwdown').html(response);
 });
});
});
```

and my functions.php is:

```
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_finescroolname', 'finescroolname' );
  function finescroolname(){
    global $wpdb;
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $school_query = "SELECT DISTINCT schoolname from wp_db where zipcode='.$postcode.'";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($school_query);
    $html = 'drop down html';
    echo $html;
    wp_die();
  }
```

So my question is about this part, how am i gonna be able to pass these results into a dropdown list in wordpress? Is it going to  be with ajax? Can anyone help with a little block of code that can lead me to result? Thank you for your time and attention. So with @user3888958 help i can see the result in ajax post:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#findschoolname").click(function(){
    var postcode = jQuery('.postcode').val();
    var postData = {
        action: 'finescroolname',
        postcode: postcode,
    }
    var adminurl = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, postData, function(response) {
        jQuery('#replacedropwdown').html(response);
    });
}); 
});
</script>
```

but still it doesnt pass the value of postcode into dropdown, when i try to debug finescroolname() function in functions.php i couldnt see any postal code pass in there.

Comment: this would be done with ajax. on change of first dropdown it will fetch the results and put in the second dropdown. i have created something similar here.. http://www.kidslunch.net/

Answer (score 1):

In the below code when you press button with the id `findschoolname` ajax will run. you can change the click event with on change of text box.
the below script run ajax.

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="zipcode">Zip Codes
         <input type="text" class="form-control postcode" name="postalCode" />
         <input type="button" id="findschoolname">
       </div>
       <div id="replacedropwdown"> 

       </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#findschoolname").click(function(){
        var postcode = jQuery('.postcode').val();
        var postData = {
            action: 'finescroolname',
            postcode: postcode,
        }
        var adminurl = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, postData, function(response) {
            jQuery('#replacedropwdown').html(response);
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Put the below code in function.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_finescroolname', 'finescroolname' );
function finescroolname(){    
    global $wpdb; 
    $postcode = intval( $_POST['postcode'] );

    $school_query = "SELECT DISTINCT schoolname from wp_db where zipcode='.$postcode.'";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($school_query);
    // Create html here and echo it;
    $html = 'drop down html';
    echo $html;
    wp_die(); 
}
```

Hope it will help a little.

Comment: Thanks for your time, i guess i have to  loop through $results in function.php and pass it to $html variable and display it in template?

Comment: Yes, create the html using your $result variable and echo it.

Comment: Thank you this worked, but somehow i am able to see ajax response when i am logged in as an admin but when i log out, there is no ajax repsonse.

Comment: Welcome, To make it work after you logged out you need to add following code as well in function.php
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_finescroolname', 'finescroolname' );